# Can Visual Studio replace MS Sql Server Manager?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I've been using Dreamweaver and MS SQL Server Management tool. I've recently got Visual Studio 12. I would like to only use Visual Studio.

When I right click on a table in the db I don't get the Script Table As options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and it's not intended to. SSMS has a lot of functionality which Visual Studio's Server Explorer doesn't, and shouldn't, attempt to reproduce.

For certain use cases, you may only need the functionality exposed within Visual Studio. But I wouldn't want to be without SSMS and all of the tools it includes. Trying to limit your usage to only VS sounds like cutting off your nose to spite your face.

Comment: OK, how can I extend SSMS to be a more robust text editor. Collapse of sections, multi cursor, multi copy past, code snippets, features that are found in more modern text editor?

Comment: @Coop Simple, [use the 2014 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299) - it does all of those things and more (except I don't know what "multi cursor" means). If you can't move to a modern version, there are add-ins like [SSMS Tools Pack](http://ssmstoolspack.com/) (free for 2008 / 2008 R2, $ for newer versions of SSMS) that can help fill some of those gaps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a complete administration of your database I would recommend you to use MS SQL Server Management tool, because you can to do tasks like:

- Administrator privileges
- Security
- Maintenance plans

(Only mentioning a couple of tasks. There are more.)

If you want to create a fast DB with the basic tasks with VStudio will be enough.

I will write a couple of links that you can visit, I hope this can help you more:

- [SQL Server- video tutorials](http://www.lynda.com/SQL-Server-training-tutorials/456-0.html)
- [MsSQL - Tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/listtutorials/mssql/1)